# Java: small key/value persister

Tags: java, persistence, key-value

I need a very lightweight and persistent key/value-store in Java.
The amount of data is very very low and it should be very simple (getter and setter and all can operate on strings).

So I think of using some small NoSQL-DB or even giving some integrated collection a serializer/deserializer to the filesystem.

But I think NoSQL is a overkill and I hope a persister also exists for such a simple requirement.

Whats the best approach here? Any ideas?

Comment: Looked into [mapdb](http://www.mapdb.org/)?

Comment: Was hoping for something that may already included in the JDK. If not I think that is a nice and lightweight solution.

Comment: ```java.util.Properties```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either implement your own thing if it is a simple key-value string. (Have a look at Java's [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.html) class too in case it suits your requirements).

If your requirements are slightly more complex have a look at the embedded lightweight databases you can use. Maybe [BerkleyDB](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/berkeleydb/overview/index.html) might work for you. There are [quite a number of others](http://embedded-databases.com/) if you do a bit of search.

Also think about what you actually need to do with the data. Do you need to query it (so it needs to be indexed?) or do you just want to load it back all into memory? (in which case using a simple JSON or YAML text format would also suffice.)

Answer (score 1):

Most `Map<String,String>` can be serialized. So for example look into https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html
there you find Serializable. Under that point information to help yourself solve the Problem.